# Copy Paste of Document Link & DB does not work in XPage CKEditor

Tags: xpages

Copy & paste of lotus doc link and db link are not working for all users. Like it works for me in FF; IE10 & Chrome but not for most of the users. It comes as raw XML format and not getting converted to click able link that happens in sametime

Why is that happening and workaround for this please?

Answer (score 1):

Get the other users to log in on your browser or vice versa. This will confirm if it's a Domino issue or a browser configuration issue. It's also working for me in a copy of the Discussion template, with various users.

From my tests, I suspect it will be down to browser configuration.

If using the same browser you get different outcomes for different users, then check the settings on the relevant Rich Text component, specifically around Active Content Filtering.

Comment: It is not domino issue; once it is pasted then it is coming like below in CKEditor <NDL>
<REPLICA 482578C0:0028A053>... It is not converting to proper link that can be clicked.

Comment: It sounds like something must be different in browser configuration

Comment: It looks this to me as well; can you please share any idea what it can be?

Comment: I don't know, I've not encountered it before. Best recommendation is to review the settings on a browser that works and one that doesn't, troubleshoot from there.